# TradingView's ‘undeclared identifier’ error in pine editor

Tags: pine-script, undeclared-identifier

Have a problem with custom identifier in pine on tradingview:

```
smma(src, length) =>
   smma = na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
   smma
```

Got error in line 2: Undeclared identifier`smma` Anybody know how to fix it ? Will be appreciate for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one of these will work. Need to declare variables before referring to them:

```
//@version=4
study("","",true)

smma(src, length) =>
    float smma = na
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length

smma2(src, length) =>
    var float smma = na
    smma := na(smma) ? sma(src, length) : (smma * (length - 1) + src) / length

plot(smma(close, 20))
plot(smma2(close, 20), "", color.blue, 6, transp = 80)
```

Comment: I'm trying both, but got ```syntax error at input `smma` ``` So, I'm just remove float value for expression and it works ! Thank You, Man !

Comment: This means your script is using a Pine version earlier than v4, and in that case you should only use the first `smma()` function in the answer, and removing `float` as you did was exactly what was needed. It's important, when you post code, to let us know which version of Pine you are using. That's what the `//@version=x` compiler directive at the beginning of your script does. If there is none, v1 is used, which is not ideal.